# Using duplicity in a disaster recovery scenario

Tags: debian, backup, disaster-recovery, duplicity

I am using duplicity for backups on my Debian servers. I have successfully backed up and restored files using duplicity.

In my backup script, I have `/usr/bin/dpkg --get-selections > /installed_packages_<hostname>` so that I can backup the package list for an easy restore of all installed packages.

Considering all packages get the default package maintainer's version of the configuration, is it possible to tell duplicity to overwrite the destination files and folders? Essentially, is it possible to overwrite `/` with yesterday's full/incremental backup?

Comment: You really should handle packages with a configuration management system like Ansible/Puppet/Chef.

Comment: We use puppet. Sometimes we forgo the puppet route for a single package that doesn't need to be managed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you restore from duplicity to a different location (probably on a different machine), then use file system tools to copy files into place. That way you can overwrite whichever you choose.

Just in case you haven't thought of it: Your strategy assumes that all packages were up-to-date when the backup was created.